# Selenium: Execute multiple testcases/testsuite from command line on selenium standalone server

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, webautomation

I have seen lot of examples where provision is given to execute a htmlSuite in selenium using following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/webpage" "./testSuite.html" "result.html"
```

But my requirement is slightly different like this

1. Few testcases/testsuites recorded via Selenium IDE ( in html format).
2. Run Selenium server (from command line).
3. Send one test case /test suite for execution (from command line)
4. After execution, browser should not close.
5. Perform some action ( from shell)
6. Send next testcase/testsuite for execution which will execute on the same browser session.
7. Perform again shell action and so on..

Is it possible in this manner or what is the possible solution closest to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle Selenium with TestNG to create a test suite and run the complete suite together.

Comment: I want each test case to be triggered by control rather than a batch execution as i have to do some operation in after the end of each testcase. 1. Execute one testcase, 2. Do some operation based on outcome 3. Proceed to next testcase